# Getting initial object from promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I would like access to the original jqXHR object as called by $.ajax(ajaxOpts), is this possible somehow? All I get now is a promise.

```
                var jqXHR = $.ajax(ajaxOpts)
                    .done(dfd.resolve)
                    .fail(dfd.reject)
                    .then(next, next);
```

Comment: Um, why are you passing some `dfd.resolve` and `dfd.reject` functions as handlers on a promise?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> The jqXHR objects returned by $.ajax() as of jQuery 1.5 implement the
>   Promise interface, giving them all the properties, methods, and
>   behavior of a Promise (see Deferred object for more information)

You already get a jqXHR object (which is a superset of the XMLHTTPRequest object). It just implements the promise interface.

```
var jqXHR = $.ajax(ajaxOpts);
console.log(typeof jqXHR.abort);
jqXHR.done(dfd.resolve)
    .fail(dfd.reject)
    .then(next, next);
```

Comment: jqXHR console.log'd is this: http://imgur.com/IYgpQeB - which has no abort method any more amongst other things. How do I get the raw object?

Comment: You must have `console.log`'d the result of your chain (`.then()`) instead of the result of `$.ajax`

Comment: Ah, yes, the result of `$.ajax` is a `jqXHR`, and `done` also returns it, but `then` does **not** return it, it returns a promise object instead. So @Wesley, your original code (in your question) was not getting the `jqXHR` object, but if you break it up like RGraham has above, you will. This may shine some light: http://jsbin.com/robuvoxe/1/edit